# What does this text from The Haunted House by Charles Dickens mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Who is—or who was—the hooded woman with the owl? Do you know?”
>
> “Well!” said Ikey, holding up his cap with one hand while he scratched his head with the other, “they say, in general, that she was murdered, and the howl he 'ooted the while.”
>
> This very concise summary of the facts was all I could learn, except that a young man, as hearty and likely a young man as ever I see, **had been took with fits and held down in 'em**, after seeing the hooded woman. Also, that a personage, dimly described as “a hold chap, a sort of one-eyed tramp, answering to the name of Joby, unless you challenged him as Greenwood, and then he said, ‘Why not? and even if so, mind your own business,’” had encountered the hooded woman, a matter of five or six times. But, I was not materially assisted by these witnesses: inasmuch as the first was in California, and the last was, as Ikey said (and he was confirmed by the landlord), Anywheres.
>     —  Charles Dickens, [*The Haunted House: The Mortals in the House*](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/67/dickens-christmas-stories/5646/the-haunted-house-the-mortals-in-the-house/)

There is nothing written about “being taken with fits and hold down in them” in any dictionary.

This is what I don't understand.

Comment: Hi Hamed, and welcome to ELL. Could you state what you think it means?

Comment: ...or at least what specific part of it is giving you trouble. Are there words you don't understand in this context, even after looking them up?

Comment: I have no idea, since there is nothing written about 'being taken with fits and hold down in them'. not in any dictionary nor in Google. I don't know what kind of language this is anymore.

Comment: had been took with fits and held down in 'em   this is what I don't understand.

Comment: This is not the English that is currently being spoken, that's for sure. The Haunted House was written in 1859, for starters, and Dickens in particular even plays a little loose with the grammar of his time.

Comment: These parts are common enough to current English that I felt fine answering them below. In general, however, you will find that non-standard English (such as written by Dickens in 1859) is not considered good material for learning English and therefore may not be well suited for this particular Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have no problem with Dickensian questions here. An O.P. might want to add a caveat at the end – something like, _I realize this is not contemporary English but I'm still interested in its meaning._ That might help ward off a host of well-meaning comments by others. Still, there's nothing wrong with questions that might not be terribly easy to answer.

Comment: @J.R. I clearly don't have a problem with it either, and I don't think anyone would object to a question purely on the grounds that it's too difficult. What I don't want is for a new user to be confused if and when we actually start doing what Matt is talking about [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/662/should-we-try-to-avoid-judgmental-comments#comment-1313) and [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/662/should-we-try-to-avoid-judgmental-comments#comment-1315).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I think you mean that Dickens' *characters* play fast and loose with the grammar. The *fits* sentence is clearly the narrator quoting Ikey in the third person.

Comment: @StoneyB What I mean is that reading Dickens is not an efficient path to speaking fluent English (to anyone who is not a Dickens character).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Oh, quite. I was just concerned to protect Dickens' reputation! (as if he needed my help) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> had been took with fits

had become afflicted by "fits":  *a sudden, acute attack or manifestation of a disease, especially one marked by **convulsions** or unconsciousness*

> and held down in 'em

had these convulsions so badly that he had to be physically restrained.

> Also, that a personage, dimly described as "a hold chap, a sort of one-eyed tramp, answering to the name of Joby, unless you challenged him as Greenwood, and then he said, 'Why not? and even if so, mind your own business,'" had encountered the hooded woman, a matter of five or six times.

An older fellow had encountered the hooded woman several times.  (This person was a hobo, missing one eye, and was named "Joby"; his last name may have been "Greenwood", but he didn't like to have it used.)

Answer (score 0):

To the question as clarified in comments above:

"Fits" in this case is basically what we would now call a seizure.

Being “t[aken] with” them means that they have afflicted him and caused him to lose control of his body.

Upon seeing the ghost of the murdered woman, the young man had a violent reaction: 

he fell, shaking, unable to rise.

---

*Dickens normally requires a bit of “translation” for even native speakers to understand him perfectly. You may wish to find an updated or heavily annotated version of the book if you truly wish to read it.*

Comment: I wish there was, but there is not.